# PHP variable equals true no matter what the value, even 0

Tags: php, variables

This is the var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (8) { 
    ["SETTING_ID"]=> string(2) "25" 
    ["SETTING_SOURCE"]=> string(2) "XV" 
    ["SETTING_FLEET"]=> string(3) "313" 
    ["SETTING_EXAM"]=> string(1) "A" 
    ["SETTING_HIDE"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["SETTING_THRESHOLD"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["SETTING_COUNT"]=> string(8) "POSITIVE" 
    ["SETTING_USAGE"]=> string(7) "MILEAGE" 
}
```

The variable I am testing is SETTING_HIDE. This is being pulled from MySQL using the Code igniter framework. I don't know if it is just me being thick after a rather long day at work or what, but no matter what value the variable holds, any if statement made against it returns true, even when typecast as a boolean or a direct string comparison, ie. == "0" or == "1".

Anyone with a fresh pair of eyes care to make me feel silly!?! :)

Just to clarify:

Have tried the following:

```
if($examSetting->SETTING_HIDE == "1") {  $showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\""; } 
if((bool)$examSetting->SETTING_HIDE) {   $showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\""; }



if($examSetting->SETTING_COUNT == "POSITIVE") further on in my code works perfectly.
```

Comment: paste your `if else statement`

Comment: Take a look at this truth table: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Have tried the following:

if($examSetting->SETTING_HIDE == "1") {        $showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\"";
}

if((bool)$examSetting->SETTING_HIDE) {        $showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\"";
}

Comment: Do you get the same result if you test SETTING_THRESHOLD ?

Comment: what you get `var_dump($examSetting->SETTING_HIDE)` ??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first example. Your problem is whatever you do with `$showOnABC` later in the code. You should add an `exit()` or something like that in the `if` to verify it and rule out other code.

Comment: Use strict comparison `===` if you want to be on the safe side.

Comment: string(1) "0" - I already checked this, which is why am am so puzzled!

I know there is nothing wrong with the statement, $showOnABC never gets re-assigned, only echoed into some HTML. I've tried testing the statement various ways, but it always returns true.

Comment: Tried === and even as a bool, an integer, whatever, it always returns true!

Comment: @JohnB in this case ===, i.e. $examSetting->SETTING_HIDE === TRUE will always return false because he's getting back a string

Comment: Cast your values BEFORE assingning to your objetc properties.

Comment: @kaigoh how are you verifying that it always returns true? It seems like you're relying on the action of checked=\"checked\ to verify this. From your code it shouldn't always be returning true. Do a comparison on SETTING_HIDE and log the result differently to verify

Comment: Try `if((int) $examSetting->SETTING_HIDE == 1)`

Comment: @GDB - first thing I tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just one of those weird annoying things, but,

```
if($examSetting->SETTING_HIDE == "1") {
$showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\"";
} else {
$showOnABC = "";
}
```

now works exactly as expected.

Thanks for looking anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($examSetting->SETTING_HIDE !== "0") {  $showOnABC = "checked=\"checked\""; }
```

might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please see: http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_kaigoh.php Which leads me to conclude that there is something else in play here, perhaps another block of code?

```
<?php // RAY_temp_kaigoh.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

$thing = new StdClass;
$thing->SETTING_ID        = "25";
$thing->SETTING_SOURCE    = "XV";
$thing->SETTING_FLEET     = "313";
$thing->SETTING_EXAM      = "A";
$thing->SETTING_HIDE      = "0";
$thing->SETTING_THRESHOLD = "0";
$thing->SETTING_COUNT     = "POSITIVE";
$thing->SETTING_USAGE     = "MILEAGE";

var_dump($thing);

if ( $thing->SETTING_HIDE) echo "TRUTHY";
if (!$thing->SETTING_HIDE) echo "FALSY";
```

Comment: Ray, many thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

But with no code change just a refresh, it has started working exactly as it should. Most odd.